# Online Python Compiler - Invalid syntax when using “print"

Tags: python, printing

Simplified code that can reproduce the issue:

```
import numpy as nup
dim = nup.matrix([[3, 0, 0],
                 [0, 2, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1]]
print("")
print(dim)
```

The whole code with detailed explanation is in the following link:
[online Python compiler](http://tpcg.io/SjDneH)

**Issue:** The code gives me error at line 81 of "print" function pointing at t:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm working with Online Python Compiler (Python v2.7.13).

Comment: You didn't close the parenthesis on the line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a parenthesis in line 80.
It should be

```
[0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: thank you so much. I am just a newbie here to use Python. Appreciate for the help!